# Repository with multiple DBContexts or multiple repositories each with a DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a web API with a resource and its sub-resources. Because the API will be hosted on multiple servers with varying database schemas (which I cannot change), I needed to create different implementations of the `DBContext` and create some logic in `Startup.cs` that handles context binding based on a property in `appsettings.json`.  Some of the servers store the resource data on different databases, which means I have to use multiple `DBContext` for those servers' implementations.

The question arises how should I structure the repositories and contexts in a way that minimizes code duplication while also keeping code bloat down?

Should I create a single repository for the resource and its sub-resources that holds multiple contexts? If so, how do I ensure my app instantiates and binds these multiple contexts to a respository?

Should I create a separate repository for each resource with each holding its corresponding context?

Am I using the wrong pattern here or misusing the pattern?

Comment: I hate to flag this and I hope others disagree but this feels very opinion based.

That asside, you may want to consider constraints beyond coding and configuring -- how much load do you need to handle; how many records; how much of the work can / should you put onto the database?

Comment: @RichardBarker Maybe I should streamline my question? I might have muddied the question by providing too much context of the problem I'm facing. I'm interested in whether or not it's bad practice for a repository to have multiple contexts -- or if it's better to have multiple repositories despite the fact the resources they represent are connected.

Comment: As Alexander says, you must have well defined abstractions in your structure. If you can reduce your structure down to a few base interfaces and abstract classes you'll make the path you need to take much clearer. You'll also want to make use of dependency injection to get the right contexts in the right repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Most importantly, you must have defined abstractions for working with data. These are interfaces. A lot of small interfaces that follow the principles of SOLID.

For example:

```
interface IUser
{
    User GetById(int id);
    void Save(User user);
}
```

Moreover, you can go further and break this interface into even smaller ones:

```
interface IGetUser
{
    User GetById(int id);
}

interface ISaveUser
{
    void Save(User user);
}
```

This is instead of one huge `IRepository` interface, with dozens and hundreds of methods.

Then you use these interfaces in your code without much thinking about how they are implemented.

Now you can use a mini-repository like this in one place:

```
class FirstUserRepository : IUser
{
    private FirstContext _context;

    // here constructor

    public User GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
    }
    // ...
}
```

And such in another place:

```
class SecondUserRepository : IUser
{
    private SecondContext _context;
    //...
}
```

Accordingly, the necessary context implementations are created, linked to different databases.

```
// Connect to a one database
class FirstContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

// Connect to an another database
class SecondContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And so on.